# How can I print randomly radius sized circles?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a below code. It prints circles with randomly ditsributed but with same radius size. How can I change it to randomly radius sized too? I want randomly distributed and randomly sized circles.

```
from random import randint
from svg_turtle import SvgTurtle
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle
import turtle 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import json


def x_circle(x, width, height):
    x_r=30
    x_num = 100
    cursor_size = 20
    x.hideturtle()
    x.screen.bgcolor("black")
    x.color("white")
    x.shape("circle")
    x.shapesize(x_r / cursor_size)
    x.speed("fastest")
    x.penup()
    xs = [] 
    
    for _ in range(x_num):
        xx = x.clone()
        xx.setposition(
            randint(-width / 2, width / 2),
            randint(-height / 2, height / 2),
        )

        while any((a.distance(xx) < x_r for a in xs)):
            xx.setposition(
                xx(- width / 2, width / 2 ),
                randint(- height / 2, height / 2),
            )
        
        x.stamp()
        


        xs.append(xx)
```

Comment: What happens if you set `shapesize` using a `randint` too?

Comment: I got error in that case @doctorlove

Comment: @user20442423 which error did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `randint` in the `shapesize` method and move it inside the for loop. Here's the modified code:

```py
def x_circle(x, width, height):
    x_r = 30
    x_num = 100
    cursor_size = 20
    x.hideturtle()
    x.screen.bgcolor("black")
    x.color("white")
    x.shape("circle")
    x.speed("fastest")
    x.penup()
    xs = []

    for _ in range(x_num):
        xx = x.clone()
        xx.setposition(
            randint(-width / 2, width / 2),
            randint(-height / 2, height / 2),
        )
        # random shape size
        x.shapesize(randint(10, 50) / cursor_size)

        while any((a.distance(xx) < x_r for a in xs)):
            xx.setposition(
                randint(-width / 2, width / 2),
                randint(-height / 2, height / 2),
            )

        xx.stamp()
        xs.append(xx)
```

The above code produces the following image:
[image: Random size circles]